Surface integral coming in wave equation
The following surface integral comes to solve wave equation in 2D case from Evans book: https://math24.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/partial-differential-equations-by-evans.pdf, page 73.
Let $x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\bar{x}=(x_1,x_2,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. For a given function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, we define $\bar{g}(\bar{x})=g(x_1,x_2)$. We denote by $\bar{B}(\bar{x},t)$ a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with center $\bar{x}$ and radius $t>0$ and $d\bar{S}$ denotes the two-dimensional surface measure on $\partial\bar{B}(\bar{x},t)$. Also, $B(x,t)$ denotes the ball of radius $t$ with centre $x$. Can someone please help me how to prove the following:
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi t^2}\int_{\partial\bar{B}(\bar{x},t)}\bar{g}\,d\bar{S}=\frac{2}{4\pi t^2}\int_{B(x,t)}g(y)\sqrt{1+|D\gamma(y)|^2}\, dy,
$$
where $\gamma(y)=\sqrt{(t^2-|y-x|^2)}$ for $y\in B(x,t)$.
